# Django url tag - static versus dynamic "path.to.view" parameter

Tags: django, django-templates, django-1.4

I'm new to Django and puzzled.  Using Django 1.4.  Inside one of my templates, this code works:

```
{% for element0, element1 in menu.elements %}
    <li class='menu_{{ name }}'><a href="{% url users.views.home %}">{{ element0 }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

... but this code throws a "NoReverseMatch" error:

```
{% for element0, element1 in menu.elements %}
    <li class='menu_{{ name }}'><a href="{% url element1 %}">{{ element0 }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

... despite the fact that the "element1" variable holds 'users.views.home'.  I'm thinking/hoping that the solution to this is really simple... that I've missed something obvious about variable handling inside Django templates?

I've consulted the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#url) for the url built-in function to no avail.  Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add this to your template:

```
{% load url from future %}
```

and change the first call to

```
 {% url 'users.views.home' %}
```

see the forwards compatibility note in the docs you linked to

Comment: perfect.  +1 and will be accepted in 4 minutes once the system allows me to.  worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

That's bad idea to write like this `{% url 'users.views.home' %}`, better use named url - `{% url 'users_home' %}`, it will be easy to maintain in the future. For example if you decide to move your `def home(request)` from `users.views` to `account.views` you will need to replace all urls occurrences in all your templates. But if you use named urls, you just need to change `urls.py`